# How can I sum numbers on lines in a file

Tags: bash, files

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1
3
4
1
4
3
1
2
```

How can I find the total of this (i.e. 1+3+4+1+4+3+1+2 = 19)?

Comment: For context, I'm counting the number of badges I have on Ask Ubuntu from the Stack Exchange API.

Comment: With `cat badges.json | grep -o '"award_count":[0-9],"rank":"gold"' | grep -o [0-9]`

Comment: Although I now realise the API has a `badge_count` method.

Comment: If you are counting the badges from the API, the language you are using to query the API can't do this (python, javascript)?

Comment: @Braiam I was using `wget`. I'm now using Javascript (long story).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702564/how-can-i-quickly-sum-all-numbers-in-a-file, also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789806/command-line-utility-to-print-statistics-of-numbers-in-linux

Comment: @muru Uh thanks, it's been answered here now tho. Ta

Comment: for the `awk` based solution go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450799/52074) because it is both easier to remember and about twice as fast as `paste|bc`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`bc` with a little help from `paste` to get the lines in a single one with `+` as the separator:

```
paste -sd+ file.txt | bc
```

To use the output of `grep` (or any other command) instead a static file, pass the `grep`'s STDOUT to the STDIN of `paste`:

```
grep .... | paste -sd+ | bc
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt            
1
3
4
1
4
3
1
2

% paste -sd+ file.txt | bc
19

% grep . file.txt | paste -sd+ | bc
19
```

---

If you must use `bash`, then you can use an array to save the file contents and then iterate over the elements or you can read the file line by line and do the sum for each line, the second approach would be more efficient:

```
$ time { nums=$(<file.txt); for i in ${nums[@]}; do (( sum+=i )); done; echo $sum ;}
19

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time { while read i; do (( sum+=i )); done <file.txt; echo $sum ;}
19

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: the stdin way didn't work for me until I discovered in another answer that I had to use `paste -sd+ -`. Please amend that.

Comment: I was suprised to find that the `awk` solution below runs about 30% faster for me... (On a 14,776,616 row file)

Answer (score 28):

You could use awk, too. To count the total number of lines in ***.txt** files that contain the word "hello":

```
grep -ch 'hello' *.txt | awk '{n += $1}; END{print n}'
```

To simply sum the numbers in a file:

```
awk '{n += $1}; END{print n}' file.txt
```

Comment: But if that line has the value "4" it won't count 4 will it. It will count 1.

Comment: No, it will count 4.

Comment: I want the total of the numbers in a file. Does this do that?

Comment: I thought you changed your question to the output of grep. I was making some assumptions. I'll add how to simply sum the values in a file.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, that makes sense! So `cat file | awk '{n += $1}; END{print n}'` does that? Nice.

Comment: Yeah. It's really the same answer as heemayl's, but instead of paste and bc it uses awk, which ultimately gives a lot more flexibility. Still, his answer is good and he was first so he deserves your vote!

Comment: +1 The use of `awk`, as shown here, is the canonical *nix way to sum numbers in a file.

Comment: `awk` is awesome, thanks for this simple and easy solution!

Answer (score 16):

#### Use `numsum` from the package `num-utils`!

(You may need to `sudo apt-get install num-utils`)

The command `numsum` does just what you need by default;

```
$ numsum file.txt 
19
```

Reading the test numbers line by line from `stdin`:

```
$ printf '
1 
3
4
1
4
3
1
2' | numsum
19
```

Or reading from one line:

```
$ printf '1 3 4 1 4 3 1 2' | numsum -r
19
```

#### More utilities

The package contains some other utilities for number processing that deserve to be more well known:

```
numaverage   - find the average of the numbers, or the mode or median
numbound     - find minimum of maximum of all lines
numgrep      - to find numbers matching ranges or sets
numinterval  - roughly like the first derivative
numnormalize - normalize numbers to an interval, like 0-1
numrandom    - random numbers from ranges or sets, eg odd.  
numrange     - similar to seq
numround     - round numbers up, down or to nearest
```

and a more general calculator command `numprocess`,
that applies an expression from the command line to numbers on input lines.

Comment: Wheil I like  options, this package is written in Perl; it's far less performant that `awk`.  `numsum` 41sec for what `awk` can do in 4.5s

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`, a native linux application usefull to scanning and processing files with a pattern per line. For your question, this will produce what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN { sum=0 } { sum+=$1 } END {print sum }' file.txt
```

Pipes are also accept:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { sum=0 } { sum+=$1 } END {print sum }'
```

Comment: There's no need for a `BEGIN{}` block, see [CrazyApe84's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/785043/85695).

Comment: It is redundant to this problem but I've preferred to include it due a didactic purpose .

Comment: But what does it teach? It is redundant to every problem, `awk` is not C, you don't need to set a variable before using it. Try `awk 'BEGIN{print c+=1}'`.

Comment: `BEGIN {}` block wasn't designed just to initialize variables. It takes part on design specification. So, on some problems it could be needed.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to use a built-in feature of your shell:

```
SUM=0; while read N; do SUM=$((SUM+N)); done </path/to/file
echo $SUM
```

This reads your file linewise, sums up and prints the result.

If you want to use a pipe and only use the 1st row, it works like this:

```
SUM=0
your_command | while read -r LINE; do for N in $LINE; do break; done; SUM=$((SUM+N)); done
echo $SUM
```

Getting the first element is done like this:

```
LIST="foo bar baz"
for OBJ in $LIST; do break; done
echo $OBJ

foo
```

Comment: A better `bash` solution, as this streams file file.  Howeve, its still very slow in comparison to `awk`.   For nearly 15 million lines, this took over 2 minutes, vs < 8 second in awk.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
$ perl -lnae '$c+=$_;END{print $c}' input.txt                                                                            
19
```

The above can sum all numbers across multiple files:

```
$ perl -lnae '$c+=$_;END{print $c}' input.txt input2.txt                                                                 
34
```

For multiple files given on command-line where we want to see sum of numbers in individual file we can do this:

```
$ perl -lnae '$c+=$_;if(eof){printf("%d %s\n",$c,$ARGV);$c=0}' input.txt input2.txt                                      
19 input.txt
15 input2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple use of `bash` scripting.

```
SUM=0; for line in `cat file.txt`; do SUM=$((SUM + line)); done
```

Comment: This is much simpler and toolset minimalistic than the current solution.

Comment: Upvote for the simple approach, thanks!  However I should mention it's not safe to use `SUM` as this redefines the built-in `SUM` in `/usr/bin/SUM`.

Comment: Don't do this on a large file: it forces the whole file to be read into a "temp" variable, rather than streaming the numbers line by line.  Not a great option.